# Is there a way to convert IE favourites to Firefox's bookmark.htm format?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks

After switching from Windows to Linux, I am left with a favourite directory containing subfolders and `.url` files, each file containing a few lines of text that look like this:

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.example.com/faq.html
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.example.com/faq.html
Modified=70E5E788C3B9C9010A
```

Since I do not have internet explorer installed on my Linux system, it is not possible for me to import the bookmarks directly to my current Firefox browser.

I was wondering if there is a quick way to extract the URL from all the `.url` files, together with the filenames to generate a `.htm` file which I can import to any modern browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a little perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use HTML::Entities qw(encode_entities);
use Config::IniFiles;
use File::Spec;

foreach my $f (@ARGV) {
    my $ini = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => $f );
    my (undef, undef, $name) = File::Spec->splitpath($f);
    $name =~ s/\.url$//;            # / # this comment un-confuses the syntax highlighter
    my $name_esc = encode_entities($name);
    my $url_esc = encode_entities($ini->val('InternetShortcut', 'URL'));
    print <<HTML
<a href="$url_esc">$name_esc</a>
HTML
}
```

That should handle everything well. You chould use `grep` & `cut`, but then you'd have to hope escaping isn't required, and that the sections in the ini-format .url file don't matter.

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. I spent half a day crash course on perl and finally got this to work. For those uninitiated, first you need to install gcc compiler, then the two modules `HTML::ENtities` and `Config::IniFiles`. The path to these modules may be in root, and may require `use lib`. And `@ARGV` contains the input of file paths.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow Not sure which distro you're running, but I'm surprised there weren't packages for those two modules. But I fully encourage learning at least a little Perl (or Ruby, or Python), they can quickly solve all sorts of problems like this.